# Perl:Opening a New Command Window and Running a Perl Script from this New Cmd Window

Tags: perl, window, cmd, system

I would like to spawn a DOS Cmd window and run hello.pl in the new cmd window.

```
    my $cmd="cd C:/run_dir && perl hello.pl";
    system("start cmd.exe /k $cmd");
```

The code above will correctly spawn the new dos cmd window.
However, the hello.pl program will execute from the window that the perl program was called from.
I would like "hello.pl" to run  from the newly spawned cmd dos window C:/run_dir.

Thanks!
sammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is

```
start cmd /k "cd c:\run_dir && perl hello.pl"
```

so you want

```
system('start cmd /k "cd c:\run_dir && perl hello.pl"');
```

Comment: system(qq{start cmd /k "cd C:\\run_dir && perl       C:\\perl_examples\\hello.pl"});

Comment: I should have used single quotes. That way you don't need to escape the `\ `. Fixed.

Comment: The command works great. Thanks. And of course, single quotes work since there is no interpolation. Now I tried to enclose the two instructions in a cmd and still had an issue.

Comment: Still, it made me notice a problem (`\r` resulting in a carriage return). But like I said, it's fixed now.

Comment: my $cmd='cd C:\run && perl C:\perl_examples\\hello.pl';
        system(qq{start cmd /k $cmd});

Comment: Because you removed the quotes. You're running `cmd && perl` (where `cmd` executes `cd`), rather than running `cmd` (where `cmd` executes `cd && perl`).